# Group items in collection by first letter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a collection of brands, which returns an IEnumerable and have grouped the brands by first letter.

```
@{
    var brands = Service.GetBrands();

    <div class="list">
    @foreach (var brand in brands.GroupBy(x => x.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper(), (alphabet, subList) => new { Alphabet = alphabet, SubList = subList.OrderBy(x => x).ToList() }).OrderBy(x => x.Alphabet))
    {
         <h4 class="letter">@brand.Alphabet</h4>
         <div class="row">
            @foreach (var item in brand.SubList)
            {
                <div class="brand col-md-3">
                    <div class="brand__title">@item</div>
                </div>
            }
            </div>
    }
    </div>
}
```

Which render the following:

[image]

But in case no brands starts with e.g. the letter B, how can I always render the letters A-Z? Can I somehow join an array with the alphabet property?

```
char[] letterArray = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ".ToCharArray();
```

Furthermore can I group any brands starting with a number in a "0-9"-group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
char[] alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
var brands = Service.GetBrands();
var numberBrands = brands.Where(x => Char.IsDigit(x.First()));

<h4 class="letter">0-9<h4>  
    <div class="row">
        @foreach(var brand in numberBrands){
            <div class="brand col-md-3">
                <div class="brand__title">@brand</div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

foreach(var letter in alphabet){
    var subBrands = brands.Where(x => 
    x.StartsWith(letter.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .OrderBy(x => x);

    <h4 class="letter">@letter<h4>  
    <div class="row">
        @foreach(var brand in subBrands){
            <div class="brand col-md-3">
                <div class="brand__title">@brand</div>
            </div>
        }

    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It needs to be x.StartsWith(letter.ToString() since alphabet is a char array and letter is therefore a char.
However if I have brands which starts with a number or just add one to the existing array, can I then group these in a "0-9" group?

brands = brands.Concat(new[] { "3M" });

Comment: @bjarne_f I don't think it's possible to support this functionality in the same alphabet loop. However I've edited my answer to also provide the "0-9" group.

Comment: I was just doing a similar approach outside the loop by using a Regex. 

Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d", RegexOptions.None);
var numberBrands = brands.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x)).OrderBy(x => x);